# Concatenacion en os.chdir

Tags: python

```
for galaxy in xrange(10):
    for system in xrange(499):
        os.chdir('E:\Scripts')
        os.makedirs(str(galaxy)+'_'+str(system))
        os.chdir('E:\Scripts\%s_%s' % (galaxy, system)
        outfile = open('%s_%s', 'w') % (galaxy, system)
        outfile.write(str(o.galaxy_content(galaxy,system)))
        outfile.close()
        os.chdir('E:\Scripts')
```

mi problema es el siguiente, cuando quiero hacer la concatenación %s_%s para crear la carpeta con os.chdir crea todo bien, mi problema es cuando quiero crear un .txt con el nombre %s_%s ya que me dice invalid syntax.

Comment: outfile = open('%s_%s' % (galaxy, system), 'w')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas aplicando el formato de cadena sobre la llamada de una función , no sobre una cadena. Debería ser `outfile = open('%s_%s' % (galaxy, system), 'w')`. Por otro lado esta forma de formatear cadenas es antigua, el nuevo estilo es usar [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) o incluso los literales de cadena formateados si estuvieras en Python >= 3.6 (que no es tu caso):

```
for galaxy in xrange(10):
    for system in xrange(499):
        os.chdir('E:\Scripts')
        os.makedirs('{}_{}'.format(galaxy, system))
        os.chdir('E:\Scripts\{}_{}'.format(galaxy, system))
        with open('{}_{}'.format(galaxy, system), 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(str(o.galaxy_content(galaxy,system)))
        os.chdir('E:\Scripts')
```

Si quisieras añadirle la extensión `.txt` a cada archivo creado sería simplemente:

```
with open('{}_{}.txt'.format(galaxy, system), 'w') as outfile:
```

Puedes ver la documentación del estamento [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) si deseas más información al respecto.

Comment: Con python 3.6 (>=3.4) incluso podría ser más fácil con el módulo [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)